# How to combine :has() and :not() css selectors (something like `div:has(.bar:hover) :not(.foo)`)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a `<div>` only if one its paragraph gets moused-hover, while also excluding some sections from getting styled. Here is an example of HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt   
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span class=foo'>Ut enim ad minim veniam</span>, quis 
  nostrud exercitation <span class='foo'>ullamco laboris nisi</span> ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
  consequat.</p>

  <p class='bar'>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui  
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div>
```

For the CSS, I tried:

```
div:has(.bar:hover) .bar {
    color: blue 
}

div:has(.bar:hover) :not(.foo) {
    color: grey
}
```

and:

```
div:has(.bar:hover) .bar {
    color: blue 
}

div:has(.bar:hover):not(.foo) {
    color: grey
}
```

but none of these options accomplish what I would like.

I would like the first paragraph except for both `span` to get colored in grey and the second paragraph to get colored in blue. However with my current code, the first paragraph including the `span` gets coloured in grey and the second in blue: it is not excluding the `span` from getting styled.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
p:not(.bar):hover {
 color: blue;
}
.foo {
 color: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span class=foo>Ut enim ad minim veniam</span>, quis nostrud exercitation <span class=foo>ullamco laboris nisi</span> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

  <p class=bar>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least 3 rules.

```css
div:has(.bar:hover) .bar {
  color: blue
}

div:has(.bar:hover) p {
  color: grey
}

div:has(.bar:hover) p .foo {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span class="foo">Ut enim ad minim veniam</span>, quis nostrud exercitation <span class="foo">ullamco laboris nisi</span> ut
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>

  <p class="bar">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div>
```